# How to check for a NullPayload in mule dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a seen plenty of examples of checking for null in a mule data weave but none that check for a NullPayload.

When I try when `payload[1] is NullPayload` in the dataweave it complains saying `missing ':' at 'NullPayload'`. Adding the `:` results in the run time error `Invalid input ":NullPayload ", expected :trait or :type`.

I know I can't check for null since it's not the same as a NullPayload but I don't know the syntax to check for a NullPayload in a dataweave.

I'm using Mule runtime 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

`payload is :null` should work as NullPaylod is mapped to null value. Also `payload == null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
payload is :empty or payload is :null
```

Sample

```
    %dw 2.0
%output application/json
---
{
    response : "Payload Is blank" when (payload is :empty or payload is :null) otherwise "payloadData"
}
```

You can replace `"payloadData"` with `payload` as per your flow